# Why can Twitter get the user's location without the user's permission?

Tags: html, twitter, location

Just go to Twitter.com, try to tweet, click on "Add your location". Twitter can show your location without asking for your permission to access it.

How can Twitter get this when any other website would need user's permission to get user's location?

Comment: You probably already allowed it... this "website X is askin for your location" warning comes from your browser, the website can't skip/change it

Comment: I don't give permission to Twitter.com. Can you see the browser warning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They can get your location using a database that maps your IP address to the location to which it is assigned. These databases are public information and your IP address is information that the web site (obviously) has. Your location is not sent from your computer, and they have no information from your computer except what your browser sends and what they are able to crosslink using databases.

http://www.geoiptool.com/